# Execute Statement in Python error Name Not Defined

Tags: python

I am trying to use a Python list comprehension to get the Variable Name SW1 to equal the string "sw1" but I keep getting an error saying sw1 not defined

```
    VarList = ["SW1"]
    VarListEnd = ["sw1"]

    list3 = [exec("%s="%x + "%s"%y) for x in VarList for y in VarListEnd]
    list3
```

How do I amend the exec statement because that is where I think the error is? 
Really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do here. Whatever it is, there's almost certainly a better way of doing it than `exec`.

Comment: using `exec` is a bad idea

Comment: I am trying to create a variable called SW1 and assign it a string value "sw1"

Comment: You can better use a dictionary and use it as a Key value pair assign the value of key what you want.

Comment: Can I do it in a list comprehension though because I am really trying to use list comprehensions for this? Thank you for your suggestion and will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `exec` for that. To create variables, you can do

```
for name, value in zip(VarList, VarListEnd):
    locals()[name] = value
```